# Issue with buttons in <div>, 2nd button acts like 1st one

Tags: jquery, css, button, html

I'm trying to figure this out for a whole day and I just can't find the way to make it work.

I have a  which acts like tooltip. It shows under some  on mouseover and it contains 2 buttons.

HTML CODE:

```
<label id="name1" class="label" style="width: 150px;">John Smith
<div class="tp"> <!-- this is a tooltip I am talking about and it contains: -->
<button type="button" class="button" id="edit1">Edit</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="remove1">Remove</button>
</div> <!-- end of tooltip -->
</label>
```

CSS Style for tooltip:

```
div.tp {
    position:absolute; 
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
label:hover div.tp {    position: absolute; 
    display: block; 
    z-index: 140; 
    max-width: 400px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    color: #dadada; 
    background: #000000; 
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(".tp button[id^=edit]").live('click',function() { 
alert('This is edit button');
});

$(".tp button[id^=remove]").live('click',function() {
alert('This is remove button');
});
```

The problem is, when I click on first button, it works fine and shows me "This is edit button" but when I click on second (Remove) button, it shows me 2 alerts. First is "This is remove button" and second one is "This is edit button" so basically, it clicks on first button too.

I have no problem in Opera browser but in every other (Chrome, IE, FF).

UPDATE: Problem doesn't exist if I use buttons outside of tooltip div.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Best regards,
IceWave

Comment: You cannot nest a block level element inside of an inline element. Label
is an inline element, DIV is block level.

Change your markup and it will probably work, and if not using a really old version of jQuery, use on() for delegated events.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `label` tag. The default `<label>` responds on a click, and if is used with a button/checkbox/radio, etc. it selects the element, so basically if you add another button to your `<label>` tag it will hit it as the first button e.g.

```
<label id="name1" class="label" style="width: 150px;">John Smith
   <div class="tp"> <!-- this is a tooltip I am talking about and it contains: -->
      <button type='button' class='btn' id='invisible'></button>
      <button type="button" class="button" id="edit1">Edit</button>
      <button type="button" class="button" id="remove1">Remove</button>
   </div> <!-- end of tooltip -->
</label>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

So you have to hide the first button and Label now will select the buttons that you wish.

Although THIS IS JUST A PATCH, don't use something like this in your HTML code (remove label if unnecessary and don't nest it with buttons)

See jsfiddle with the fix : http://jsfiddle.net/3LD4U/1/

Comment: This is the correct answer. I knew it has nothing with jQuery. I'm still concerning is this fix better than javascript "return false;"

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually you could place `for` in the label tag like this `<label ... for="">` and you'll prevent the default button execution

Answer (score 0):

you should use directly the id of buttons not by a common div of tp

isnt it simple with jquery

```
$("#edit").click(function() {
  alert('This is edit button');
});

$("#remove").click(function() {
  alert('This is remove button');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the <div> with a <span>, which is allowed inside a <label> (<div> isn't).

Comment: at first it was a span but results were same. after that, I changed to div because I thought it might be a problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<label id="name1" class="label" style="width: 150px;">John Smith
    <span class="tp">
        <input type="button" class="button" id="edit1" value="Edit" />
        <input type="button" class="button" id="remove1" value="Remove" />
    </span>
</label>
```

You should use the newest version of jQuery and do:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^='edit']", function(e) { 
    alert('This is edit button');
});

$(document).on("click", "[id^='remove']", function() {
    alert('This is remove button');
});
```

and replace document with the closest non dynamic parent.

Comment: I got same results. I forgot to mention that this problem is maybe not related to jQuery because and without jQuery, my buttons has :hover and :active style too and, when I press and hold 2nd button, my 1st button gets :active style active also.

Comment: Try placing markup outside the label tag, and use the label tag for .... wait for it.... a label, and all your problems will be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div.tp').find('button:nth-child(1)').live('click', function(){
   alert('Edit');
});
$('div.tp').find('button:nth-child(2)').live('click', function(){
   alert('Remove');
});
```

By the way you HTML markup is wrong. You cannot place a div inside label.

Comment: Yes, I know that but as I said, at first I used span but then I tried div to see will anything happen. Got it back to span now.

Answer (score 0):

Its lable who did raise click twise.
Just add this:

```
$(".label").live('click',function() {
    return false;
});

$(".tp button[id^=edit]").live('click',function() {
    alert('This is edit button');
});

$(".tp button[id^=remove]").live('click',function() {
    alert('This is remove button');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an alternative solution but, is it proper and valid enough to escape future bugs with button clicks?

Comment: You are right.It is not proper solution. Here main problem is with Lable. If you remove it, it will work fine.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 18.0.1025.168 on MAC OS X and it does not work, you could see in the screen capture that the both buttons are in PRESSED state http://i45.tinypic.com/mwplsg.png

Answer (score 0):

you whole tooltip in wrap within `label` and this arise the problems. Try you tooltip html like this:

```
<label id="name1" class="label" style="width: 150px;">John Smith</label> <!--  label will end here-->
<div class="tp"> <!-- this is a tooltip I am talking about and it contains: -->
<button type="button" class="button" id="edit1">Edit</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="remove1">Remove</button>
</div> <!-- end of tooltip -->
```

And dont use `live()`, use `on()` instead like below:

```
$(document).on("click", "button[id^='edit']", function(e) { 
    alert('This is edit button');
});

$(document).on("click", "[id^='remove']", function(e) {
    alert('This is remove button');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/636vV/30/)